# File Not found in exe of wpf application

Tags: asp.net, wpf

When publishing the WPF application and generate an exe, I am unable to get the files which are placed in the templates-folder. When I copy my folder and files to bin it works, or if use

```
string StartUpPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
//  var gparent = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(StartUpPath).ToString()).ToString()).ToString();

ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(StartUpPath + @"\Templates\Invoice.xaml", FileMode.Open));
```

This code works fine for my local, but when I generate an exe, these files are not found.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your files aren't in the exe. I had the same problem recently.

It sounds like you need to handle your resources - there are several ways to go about this, and Microsoft has a [full explanation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8%28VS.80%29.aspx) about resources, including the difference between using **Linked** and **Embedded** Resources, and links through to other great guides.

I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio, in which case this should work;

- right click the file you can't access
- select properties (or press `ALT` + `ENTER`)
- set **Build Action** to be `Resource`
- set **Copy to Output Directory** to be `Copy if newer`
- save

... and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think it throws an exception because the file doesn't exist on that machine. You can set `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer` on property window.

These settings will make sure that you have the file to your output.

[image]